# Wrapper component for material toggle group (Angular 7)

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I'm trying to create a wrapper component for material button-toggle-group. I should add a lot of custom styling for it, so it makes sense to do this in a component so I can import this component later rather than doing it every time. However, I've hit a snag. It is only possible to click the button one time, and then it is checked forever. Also, all buttons can be checked at the same time. What I'm wondering is:

- How do I change the selected button when option is selected?
- How can I use the boolean in the dataset to set one of the buttons to checked by default?
- Also, how can I limit it to one selection at a time? I tried setting the "multiple"-parameter to false, but this does not seem to work.

I have provided what I have so far in a Stackblitz - for some reason this is not loading the material theme properly, but you can still see the problem and what I have so far:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7rxxq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `mat-button-toggle-group` is intended to be a group of several buttons... because your loop is on the `mat-button-toggle-group` you are creating two groups each containing one button.

Remove your loop from `mat-button-toggle-group`

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="optionSelected($event)" multiple="false" [name]="label">
```

Add it to the `mat-button-toggle` so you have a yes and no in one `mat-button-toggle-group`... also use `[checked]="option.value` to default the value

```
<mat-button-toggle i18n="{{option.i18n}}" [value]="option.value" [checked]="option.value" *ngFor="let option of options" style="margin-left:15%">{{option.displayValue}}</mat-button-toggle>
```

**Please Note:** once your options are in a single group, only one will ever be selected at a time... once selected you cannot deselect... you will need to do it programmatically if you need the ability to deselect.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmn4k4?embed=1&file=src/app/toggle-wrapper/toggle-wrapper.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply and help! The misplaced loop you pointed out was what was causing problems. Everything is working splendidly now! :)